# CSS Grid Unused space on left and right

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to create CSS grid components but one problem keeps poping up and for the life of me I cant find any solution.

So for a basic example:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background: black;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.item {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
</div>
```

What gives the following result:

[image]

The question is:

**How do you remove the side space, the black one to be the same as the grid gap?**

It is a bit simplistic, but a major problem. What am i missing? 
I tried margins, and puddings, all sorts of "work-around" but all of them made different problems down the way.

I feel like this had to have an answer already, but for the life of me I can't find a proper solution.

Comment: did you try this? `body{margin: 0}`

Comment: Yes, and that doesn't solve the problem. It sets the margin on the outside of the black border <div class="grid">, the problem is the <div class="item"> don't start on the very (inside) border of the <div class="grid"> but leaves a little bit of fixed space. On the top and bottom it's ok.

Comment: I'm trying to use it on Razor components in Blazor Server side application. If it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I Figured it out. So I'm not sure whether this is a bug or I'm missing something, but the solution is to wrap the grid  in to a wrapper  like:

```
<style>
.grid-container {
    border:1px solid red;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1px;
    background: black;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    border:1px solid green;
}

.item {
    background: white;
}
</style>
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="item">a</div>
        <div class="item">b</div>
        <div class="item">c</div>
        <div class="item">a</div>
        <div class="item">b</div>
        <div class="item">c</div>
        <div class="item">a</div>
        <div class="item">b</div>
        <div class="item">c</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

The wrapper (red border) takes the available space, but the grid then fits properly, without the wrapper the grid would spread out like the wrapper but behave like it was inside the wrapper.

As i mentioned in a comment this is happening with razor components in Blazor Server Side project. Not sure if this is an exclusive problem to me, the project or technology.

P.S.

The wrapper does not need a CSS class or styling, it can be a simple  tag.

Answer (score 1):

`body {margin: 0;}` works for me.

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background: black;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.item {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As i said in the comments, it doesnt solve my problem. Tried on opera and firefox. but the problem persists.

Comment: @Levidoom Sorry then. I only have what you gave us to work with. Are you inspecting the `div` in the dev console to see what css is being applied to it?

Comment: no problem man, but all the required info is given. As i said, the problem is preaty simple, the gap persists no mater what kind of margin or padding on whatever element i place it. I will try to inspect it in dev console (forgot about it, but i dont have much hope the answer lies there)